# Why doesn't the compiler allocate and deallocate local var with "sub*" and "add*" on the stack?

Tags: c, macos, assembly, compiler-construction, llvm-gcc

According to some textbooks, the compiler will use `sub*` to allocate memory for local variables.

For example, I write a Hello World program:

```
int main()
{
    puts("hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

I guess this will be compiled to some assembly code on the 64 bit OS:

```
    subq    $8, %rsp
    movq    $.LC0, (%rsp)
    calq    puts
    addq    $8, %rsp
```

The `subq` allocates 8 byte memory (size of a point) for the argument and the `addq` deallocates it.

But when I input `gcc -S hello.c` (I use the llvm-gcc on Mac OS X 10.8), I get some assembly code.

```
.section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
.globl  _main
.align  4, 0x90
_main:
Leh_func_begin1:
       pushq    %rbp
Ltmp0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp1:
    subq    $16, %rsp
Ltmp2:
    xorb    %al, %al
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, %rdi
    callq   _puts
    movl    $0, -8(%rbp)
    movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret

   .......

L_.str:
      .asciz     "hello world!"
```

Around this `callq` without any `addq` and `subq`. Why? And what is the function of `addq   $16, %rsp`?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: There's _is_ a matching `subq`/`addq` pair in the assembly output ("function prologue" and epilogue). I don't really see what your question is about.

Comment: your example allocates a function call parameter, not a local var (its the alternate method to `PUSH`). also, the compiler has aggregated the parameter and local variable allocations.

Comment: I have read a course:[Writing a compiler in Ruby bottom up](http://www.hokstad.com/writing-a-compiler-in-ruby-bottom-up-step-2.html). But his compiler output is different with mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have any local variables in your `main()`. All you may have in it is a pseudo-variable for the parameter passed to `puts()`, the address of the `"hello world"` string.

According to your last disassembly, the calling conventions appear to be such that the first parameter to `puts()` is passed in the `rdi` register and not on the stack, which is why there isn't any stack space allocated for this parameter.

However, since you're compiling your program with optimization disabled, you may encounter some unnecessary stack space allocations and reads and writes to and from that space.

This code illustrates it:

```
subq    $16, %rsp ; allocate some space
...
movl    $0, -8(%rbp) ; write to it
movl    -8(%rbp), %eax ; read back from it
movl    %eax, -4(%rbp) ; write to it
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax ; read back from it
addq    $16, %rsp
```

Those four `mov` instructions are equivalent to just one simple `movl $0, %eax`, no memory is needed to do that.

If you add an optimization switch like `-O2` in your compile command, you'll see more meaningful code in the disassembly.

Also note that some space allocations may be needed solely for the purpose of keeping the stack pointer aligned, which improves performance or avoids issues with misaligned memory accesses (you could get the #AC exception on misaligned accesses if it's enabled).

The above code shows it too. See, those four `mov` instructions only use 8 bytes of memory, while the `add` and `sub` instructions grow and shrink the stack by 16.

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer. And I get some information about this problem. Actually, the 64 bit archive use rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, r9 to pass parameter rather than pushing to stack.

Comment: 16-byte stack alignment is required for correctness because functions are allowed to use SSE loads/stores on their own stack memory: [glibc scanf Segmentation faults when called from a function that doesn't align RSP](//stackoverflow.com/q/51070716) / [Why does the x86-64 / AMD64 System V ABI mandate a 16 byte stack alignment?](//stackoverflow.com/q/49391001).  (I'm sure you came across this sometime in the 8 years since writing this answer, but commenting for future readers)

Comment: Enabling the AC flag is not really viable; gcc optimizations *will* intentionally do misaligned loads or stores sometimes, e.g. when zeroing an adjacent pair of elements in an array, like `arr[1]` and `arr[2]`.  And glibc's hand-written `memcpy` freely uses unaligned loads/stores for short copies.